# Difference between templates and themes in opencart

Tags: opencart

I am new to opencart. Can you tell me the difference between  templates and themes in opencart-2.0.3.1?

Comment: _Templates_ control the rendering of the output data on different levels, from the HTML code generated for a specific field/item (like a single product), over a list of such items, stuff like the navigation, …, and the overall page structure. Templates are usually “nested” in that regard, resp. one template calls “sub-templates” for different details. A _theme_ is a collection of templates (plus other resources such as stylesheets, JavaScript, images) bundled together to achieve a certain layout/design.

Answer (score 0):

**Very straight forward answer to your question without confusing you further.**

Both are the same things. Some people use word templates and some uses themes.